# Почему дата высчитывается некорректно?

Tags: java, android, дата

Я хочу получить дату отличающуюся на `10` дней от текущей. Получаю текущую дату с помощью

```
long date = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

Собственно, она равна `1513854052451` (21-12-2017 по нашему). Затем вычитаю из текущей даты количество дней равное `86400000 * 10`, но после отображения и форматирования с помощью `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");` выводит почему то `31-12-1969` вместо `10-12-2017`, ну никак не сходится.

```
public void add (View view)
{
    long day = 86400000;  //милис. в 1 дне
    long date = cal.getTimeInMillis(); //получаем текущую дату
    long a = Long.parseLong(remindDays.getText().toString()); // напр. в EditText введено 10
    long b = day * a; //кол-во дней в милис.
    long c = date - b; // сдвинутая дата

        db.add(add_date);
}
```

я закидываю дату в БД в виде числа, а уже оттуда в `TextView` результат вывожу и там же форматирую строку, то есть по сути ошибка где то в коде выше.

Пробовал вручную пошагово задавать конкретные цифры для теста:

```
String a = "1513854052451"; // текущая дата
String b = "1513767652451"; //текущая дата - 1 день (86400000)
String c = sdf.format(Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(b)));
tv.setText(c);
```

В этом варианте все работает, почему же в 1 случае не работает никак не могу понять, логика то такая же.

Comment: вы знаете, весь пакет Date вместе с календарем - позор Java , посему все с незапамятных времен пользовались йодатайм, который в настоящее время , начиная с java 8, стал ее частью - пакет java.time. очень рекомендую, там у вас таких проблем не будет

Comment: Укажите пожалуйста конкретные значения дат и сдвига в примере. Т.е. я конечно могу посмотреть, что за дата 1513854052451, но зачем всем читающим это делать.

Comment: ну это сегодняшняя дата 21-12-2017

Comment: Можете при отладке посмотреть какие значения получают `date`, `a`, `b` и `c`? Еще, в примере неправильного кода нет вызова `setText`, так и должно быть?

Comment: @defaultlocale текст выставляется потом, я забыл его просто вписать ввиду неважности в отношении вопроса

Comment: Но проверяется то именно текст (`31-12-1969`), так что он скорее всего важен. Вы можете дополнить свой вопрос (под ним должна быть ссылка «править»)

Comment: Попробуйте создать [воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) и указать явно ожидаемый и полученный результат. Пока пример кода вызывает множество вопросов, на которые можете ответить только Вы: что забито в `remindDays.getText()`?, как инициализируются `cal`и `sdf`? как задается текст?

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, кусок кода, где Вы переводите миллисекунды в текст

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле логика работы абсолютно верная, проблема заключалась в том, что запись производилась по проверке чек бокса. Мой вопрос в данному случае является некорректным. Код в первом случае полностью рабочий.

если кому то нужно вот полный рабочий код

```
  public void add_insurance (View view)
{
    long day = 86400000;
    String add_date = sdf.format(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    long add_date_for_sorting = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    long add_date_start = start_cal.getTimeInMillis();
    long add_date_finish = finish_cal.getTimeInMillis();
    String label = getResources().getString(R.string.Ins);
    String price = insPrice.getText().toString();



    if (remindCheck.isChecked())
    {
        long add_date_for_remind = add_date_finish - Long.parseLong(remindDays.getText().toString()) * day;
        if (add_date.length() > 0 && add_date_start > 0 && add_date_finish > 0 && price.length() > 0 && remindDays.length() > 0)
        {
            db.add_insurance_with_remind(add_date, add_date_for_sorting, add_date_start, add_date_finish, price, label, add_date_for_remind);

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.string.Added, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.string.pls_add_data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы где-то ошиблись при переводе. Вообще, рекомендую взять на вооружение удобную утилиту `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`, которая позволяет переводит время из одних единиц измерения в другие.

```
String remindDays = "10";
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
long daysInMilist = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(Long.parseLong(remindDays));
long now = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
long past = now - daysInMilist;
String formatted = new SimpleDateFormat().format(new Date(past));
```

Comment: С переводом всё нормально. Я попробовал запустить этот код, изменив кол-во дней на константу и получение текущей даты на `System.currentTimeMillis()` и всё работает корректно. Значит проблема либо в том, что `cal.getTimeMillis()` возвращает не сегодняшнюю дату, либо `remindDays.getText().toString()` накидывает пару годочков :) Первое более вероятно |
**UPD:** Пардон, увидел, что дата верная

Answer (score 0):

Если задача в быстром (в плане написания кода) получении даты, увеличенной или уменьшенной на какое-то кол-во дней/месяцев/лет, то можно просто вот так:

```
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    Log.i("TEST_DATE","cal = "+calendar.getTime());
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,10);
    Log.i("TEST_DATE","calnew = "+calendar.getTime());
```

Времени не было, по этому просто в логи вывел:

```
I/TEST_DATE: cal = Fri Dec 22 15:38:15 GMT+03:00 2017
I/TEST_DATE: calnew = Mon Jan 01 15:38:15 GMT+03:00 2018
```

Всего две строки кода